# How to exclude some directory during search(through ctrl+shift+f) in sublime 2?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want to exclude some directory like `.venv/lib/python2.7/` from the search result during the search for specific keyword, I don't want the result which come from the above directory,  Suppose I want to search keyword "subtitle", I will press `ctrl+shift+f` then in **Find :** field I will write **subtitle**, but in **Where :** what should write to exclude so that result does not come from the exclude directory. 
Let me more describe
In sublimetext2 I have open **horizon** folder. This is my project

```
/opt/stack/horizon
```

but I want to exclude `.venv` Which is in following directory, you can check this is inside **horizon** folder

```
/opt/stack/horizon/.venv/
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write the path you want to search in, then add a list of folders to ignore like this :

```
/home/me/dev/project,-/home/me/dev/project/junkfolder/*,-/home/me/dev/project/var/log/*
```

Syntax is `-path/to/ignore/*`.